# What's the English word for the Spanish "sobremesa"?

Tags: single-word-requests

In Spanish, the situation where you keep talking after the meal has ended with the people you shared your lunch or dinner is called "sobremesa" (literally over-table or after-table).  Is there a word in English to mention that situation?

Comment: "Table talk" is a term for conversation over the dinner (or other meal) table, though it's not specific to after dinner, and it's probably becoming archaic (since no one talks at dinner anymore -- too engrossed in their iPhones).

Comment: "[After dinner table talk](http://archive.org/stream/companionafterdi00pelliala/companionafterdi00pelliala_djvu.txt)", even. It's dated (archaic), though [after-dinner speeches](http://www.theguardian.com/media/2005/sep/06/politics.politicsandthemedia1) still exist for very formal dinners here in the UK.

Comment: The common phrase is "after-dinner conversation". "After-meal conversation" is used also.

Comment: @ermanen is right, "after-dinner conversation" sounds much less dated.

Comment: A word or phrase request can easily attract a long list of answers when it’s too subjective – more of a poll or request for ideas. Unfortunately neither are a good fit for the Stack Exchange model. A Stack Exchange question is objective and specific enough that it has a clearly “right” answer.

Comment: If possible, add more details of research you’ve done, especially solutions you’ve already rejected, and why. Include the desired connotation, register (formality), part of speech, and context in which it is to be used, and provide the exact enclosing sentence or passage. If this is not possible because you really do have a subjective question, a welcoming place to ask for advice is our [English Language & Usage Chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95).

Comment: @HotLicks: "Table talk" is normally used call out card players who talk too much about subjects that might reveal information about their hand to bridge partners, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Being fluent in both languages, I would have to come to the conclusion that, short of @Hot Licks suggestion of 'table talk', there really isn't a *perfect* English substitute. As mentioned, 'table talk' has no sense of order, whereas the **sobre** in 'sobremesa' conveys a sense of 'over-and-above', 'in addition to', or, in terms of time, 'after'. Also, it may just be due to the fact that, culturally, the portion after the meal in which people often talk and joke is much less a vital part of the meal itself in English-speaking countries than in their Spanish-speaking counterparts.

Answer (score 2):

There is a word for witty, philosophical chat at the dinner table, but it's taken directly from the Greek:  deipnosophy.  Someone who is particularly adept at such conversation is a deipnosophist. But you won't find one English speaker in ten thousand who knows these words.

A bit less obscure, but still rare, one could refer to a "post-prandial" chat or conversation. "Post-prandial" is actually used by doctors in reference to testing one's blood glucose level after a meal, but more typically they recommend testing "pre-prandial" (before lunch or dinnerl) or "fasting" (before breakfast) levels.